# React multiple state updates (useState) in the presence of async code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I have the following React 18 (with TypeScript) code:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get<User[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => setUsers(res.data));
  }, []);

  const addUser = () => {
    const newUser = { id: 0, name: "Test" };
    setUsers([newUser, ...users]);
    axios
      .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", newUser)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("size", users.length);
        setUsers([res.data, ...users]);
      })
      .catch((err) => setError(err.message));
  };

  return (
    <>
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <button onClick={addUser}>Add</button>
      <ul>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As far as I understand, we'll have 2 re-renders here.
The first one will render the new `Users` list with the new Test user with id = 0 appended at the beginning.

Then after the promise resolves, the second one will render the latest `Users` list again with the (returned from server) Test user with id = 11 appended at the beginning. I know about React's updates batching but these should be clearly 2 "batches" and thus 2 re-renders right?

So the result should be an incorrect list with the new user duplicated.

However, I tested this code and it correctly renders the list with **one** new user only. What am I understanding incorrectly here? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Of course I'm not talking about pressing the button many times. We should just discuss pressing the button only once.

IMO -> Result should be duplicated even in this first press

Result -> Not like that. That's why I'm really confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the result should be an incorrect list with the new user duplicated.

Keep pressing the button and this happens.  But it *doesn't* happen the first time you press the button.

Why?

This operation updates state based on the current version of `users` captured during the previous render:

```
setUsers([newUser, ...users]);
```

Then the AJAX operation is invoked, which has a callback to update state.  That callback *also* updates state based on the current version of `users` captured during the previous render, since [state was not updated when it was invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/328193):

```
setUsers([res.data, ...users]);
```

In **both** cases, `users` had the same value.  So **both** operations updated state to a single "Test" user plus the same list of existing `users`.  So the result of both operations is a new state with only one "Test" user prepended.  (This still results in two re-renders.  They just both render the same visual information and in rapid succession, so you're not observing the different IDs.)

To achieve the behavior you're expecting, you can modify your state updates to use the current version of state *in the batch processing* rather than the captured version of state from the previous render.  For example:

```
setUsers(prev => [res.data, ...prev]);
```

Comment: Yes I know about the famous "setCount(...) 3 times" example. But it's not like that in this case right? The first setUsers should trigger a re-render and actually update the state because it's inside the onClick event handler that finishes here (so, first React update batching finishes). When the promise resolves, it should be another React update batching, and the users list should be the new one, already previously updated right?

Comment: What really confuses me too is if we add a "isLoading" state variable to control a Spinner. After the first setUsers and setLoading, the component is rerendered and all state variables should be updated. Thus when the promise resolves, the "users" state variable should be the already updated one right?

Comment: @ramcrys: *"But it's not like that in this case right?"* - It is.  The component does re-render in between the two state updates, that much is true.  But the second state update is still using the same value of `users` because it was invoked from a previous render.  The callback function created a closure around that value.  This isn't really a React thing, it's how closures work in JavaScript.

Comment: Oh yes, it seems the closure part really got me. I still need to think about it for a bit more :)